# Proof by Definition: $X$ is a subset of $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove, only by definition (and valid forms of inference), that $X$ is a subset of the union of the power set of $X$, i.e. $X \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{P}(X)$. I keep getting stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions at all?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let $z \in X$. Then $\{z\} \subseteq X$, hence $\{z\} \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ (I denote by $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the powerset of $X$).
So, $z \in  \bigcup\mathcal{P}(X)$ by definition of union, since $z$ is an element of $\{z\}$ which is an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.
Therefore, $X \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{P}(X)$ because every element of $X$ is an element of $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(X)$.